# See the full body response from BidiStream Gatling

Tags: scala, grpc, gatling

Hope you are doing well,
For now I'm looking at bidiStream, now that I want to see response of the bidiStream, but it doesn't return me anything which I am not sure if the stream is running or not, as this script below:

```
val paymentFinalizerProcess_Message = (session: io.gatling.core.session.Session) => { 
    val PaymentCustomize = Payment(
        //body
    )
    val paymentResultCustomize = PaymentResult(
        //body
    )
    PaymentFinalizerRequest(
        //body
    )
  }
  val PaymentFinalizerProcess_Call = grpc("BIDIStream")
    .bidiStream[PaymentFinalizerRequest, PaymentFinalizerHandlingResponse](RelayServerGrpc.METHOD_PAYMENT_FINALIZER_PROCESS, "PaymentFinalizerProcess")

  val speaker = scenario("PaymentFinalizerProcess")
  .exec(
    PaymentFinalizerProcess_Call
      .connect
      .header(Authorization)(s"Bearer string")
      .callOptions(CallOptions.DEFAULT.withDeadlineAfter(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
      .endCheck(statusCode is Status.Code.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED)
  )
  .exec(
    PaymentFinalizerProcess_Call
      .send(paymentFinalizerProcess_Message)
  )
  .exec(PaymentFinalizerProcess_Call.reconciliate(waitFor = StreamEnd))
  setUp(
    speaker.inject(
        atOnceUsers(1)
      )
  ).protocols(grpcConf)
}
```

I think that the log level maybe being low, so I have set the root level in logback.xml to WARN level, but nothing changed, a bit help would be appreciated
Additional Info: I have set to TRACE level and tried again, log doesn't seem to show the response stream
I add up the simulation.log record

```
RUN test.scala.PaymentFinalizerProcess  paymentfinalizerprocess 1698283070288       3.9.0
USER    PaymentFinalizerProcess START   1698283071010
REQUEST     BIDIStream  1698283070849   1698283100857   OK   
USER    PaymentFinalizerProcess END 1698283100874
```

Gatling response:

```
10:17:47.826 [TRACE] i.g.a.Gatling$ - Starting
10:17:47.832 [INFO ] i.g.c.c.GatlingConfiguration$ - Gatling will try to load 'gatling.conf' config file as ClassLoader resource.
10:17:47.984 [TRACE] i.g.a.Gatling$ - Configuration loaded
10:17:47.984 [TRACE] i.g.a.Gatling$ - ActorSystem instantiated
10:17:48.279 [INFO ] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
10:17:48.511 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.l.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
10:17:48.628 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0 - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
10:17:48.629 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0 - Java version: 17
10:17:48.629 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
10:17:48.630 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
10:17:48.630 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.storeFence: available
10:17:48.631 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
10:17:48.633 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0 - direct buffer constructor: unavailable
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled
        at io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil.trySetAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:31)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$5.run(PlatformDependent0.java:288)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:282)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid(PlatformDependent.java:333)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:88)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ClassInitializerUtil.tryLoadClasses(ClassInitializerUtil.java:32)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:72)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>(Epoll.java:40)
        at io.gatling.netty.util.Transports.newEventLoopGroup(Transports.java:47)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:85)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:51)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromSbtTestFramework(Gatling.scala:47)
        at io.gatling.sbt.GatlingTask.liftedTree1$1(GatlingTask.scala:51)
        at io.gatling.sbt.GatlingTask.execute(GatlingTask.scala:50)
        at sbt.ForkMain$Run.lambda$runTest$1(ForkMain.java:413)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
10:17:48.634 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
10:17:48.635 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0 - jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$7 cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module @ba9adf9
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:560)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$7.run(PlatformDependent0.java:410)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:401)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid(PlatformDependent.java:333)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:88)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ClassInitializerUtil.tryLoadClasses(ClassInitializerUtil.java:32)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:72)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>(Epoll.java:40)
        at io.gatling.netty.util.Transports.newEventLoopGroup(Transports.java:47)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:85)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:51)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromSbtTestFramework(Gatling.scala:47)
        at io.gatling.sbt.GatlingTask.liftedTree1$1(GatlingTask.scala:51)
        at io.gatling.sbt.GatlingTask.execute(GatlingTask.scala:50)
        at sbt.ForkMain$Run.lambda$runTest$1(ForkMain.java:413)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
10:17:48.635 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): unavailable
10:17:48.636 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
10:17:48.649 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - maxDirectMemory: 1073741824 bytes (maybe)
10:17:48.650 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: C:\Users\TS-NGU~1.TRI\AppData\Local\Temp (java.io.tmpdir)
10:17:48.650 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
10:17:48.650 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - Platform: Windows
10:17:48.651 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: -1 bytes
10:17:48.651 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
10:17:48.652 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.CleanerJava9 - java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
10:17:48.652 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
10:17:48.659 [DEBUG] i.n.c.MultithreadEventLoopGroup - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 8
10:17:48.677 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.initialSize: 1024
10:17:48.677 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.maxSize: 4096
10:17:48.682 [DEBUG] i.n.c.n.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
10:17:48.682 [DEBUG] i.n.c.n.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
10:17:48.690 [DEBUG] i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
10:17:48.695 [TRACE] i.n.c.n.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WEPollSelectorImpl@47ddfd7
10:17:48.698 [TRACE] i.n.c.n.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WEPollSelectorImpl@3e57e06e
10:17:48.700 [TRACE] i.n.c.n.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WEPollSelectorImpl@67996c16
10:17:48.702 [TRACE] i.n.c.n.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WEPollSelectorImpl@18dc2a71
10:17:48.708 [TRACE] i.n.c.n.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WEPollSelectorImpl@42455023
10:17:48.711 [TRACE] i.n.c.n.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WEPollSelectorImpl@43908c95
10:17:48.714 [TRACE] i.n.c.n.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WEPollSelectorImpl@6f45a12d
10:17:48.716 [TRACE] i.n.c.n.NioEventLoop - instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WEPollSelectorImpl@16338116
10:17:48.720 [TRACE] i.g.a.Gatling$ - Runner instantiated
10:17:48.720 [TRACE] i.g.app.Runner - Running
Gatling 3.9.5 is available! (you're using 3.9.0)
10:17:50.287 [TRACE] i.g.app.Runner - Simulation params built
10:17:50.288 [TRACE] i.g.app.Runner - Before hook executed
10:17:50.309 [TRACE] i.g.app.Runner - CoreComponents instantiated
10:17:50.341 [DEBUG] c.g.p.g.g.p.GrpcProtocol$ - Making warm up call with method grpc.health.v1.Health/Check
10:17:50.494 [DEBUG] i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
10:17:50.495 [DEBUG] i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords: 4
10:17:50.499 [DEBUG] i.n.b.AbstractByteBuf - -Dio.netty.buffer.checkAccessible: true
10:17:50.500 [DEBUG] i.n.b.AbstractByteBuf - -Dio.netty.buffer.checkBounds: true
10:17:50.501 [DEBUG] i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory - Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@7a8e6023
10:17:50.554 [DEBUG] i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 8
10:17:50.554 [DEBUG] i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 8
10:17:50.555 [DEBUG] i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
10:17:50.555 [DEBUG] i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 9
10:17:50.555 [DEBUG] i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 4194304
10:17:50.555 [DEBUG] i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
10:17:50.555 [DEBUG] i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
10:17:50.555 [DEBUG] i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
10:17:50.555 [DEBUG] i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
10:17:50.555 [DEBUG] i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimIntervalMillis: 0
10:17:50.555 [DEBUG] i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.useCacheForAllThreads: false
10:17:50.555 [DEBUG] i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedByteBuffersPerChunk: 1023
10:17:50.575 [DEBUG] i.n.c.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.processId: 2940 (auto-detected)
10:17:50.577 [DEBUG] i.n.u.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: false
10:17:50.578 [DEBUG] i.n.u.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses: false
10:17:50.586 [DEBUG] i.n.u.NetUtilInitializations - Loopback interface: lo (Software Loopback Interface 1, 127.0.0.1)
10:17:50.587 [DEBUG] i.n.u.NetUtil - Failed to get SOMAXCONN from sysctl and file \proc\sys\net\core\somaxconn. Default: 200
10:17:50.605 [DEBUG] i.n.c.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.machineId: 00:05:9a:ff:fe:3c:7a:00 (auto-detected)
10:17:50.627 [DEBUG] i.n.b.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
10:17:50.628 [DEBUG] i.n.b.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 0
10:17:50.628 [DEBUG] i.n.b.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
10:17:50.642 [DEBUG] i.n.u.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 4096
10:17:50.642 [DEBUG] i.n.u.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
10:17:50.642 [DEBUG] i.n.u.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.chunkSize: 32
10:17:50.642 [DEBUG] i.n.u.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.blocking: false
10:17:50.675 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url] OUTBOUND SETTINGS: ack=false settings={ENABLE_PUSH=0, MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS=0, INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE=1048576, MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE=8192}
10:17:50.682 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url OUTBOUND WINDOW_UPDATE: streamId=0 windowSizeIncrement=983041
10:17:50.696 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url INBOUND SETTINGS: ack=false settings=[id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url
10:17:50.697 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url OUTBOUND SETTINGS: ack=true
10:17:50.714 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url OUTBOUND HEADERS: streamId=3 headers=GrpcHttp2OutboundHeaders[:authority: url, :path: /grpc.health.v1.Health/Check, :method: POST, :scheme: http, content-type: application/grpc, te: trailers, user-agent: grpc-java-netty/1.46.0, grpc-accept-encoding: gzip] streamDependency=0 weight=16 exclusive=false padding=0 endStream=false
10:17:50.722 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url OUTBOUND DATA: streamId=3 padding=0 endStream=true length=5 bytes=0000000000
10:17:50.724 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url INBOUND SETTINGS: ack=false settings={HEADER_TABLE_SIZE=4096, MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS=100, MAX_FRAME_SIZE=16384, MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE=65535}
10:17:50.724 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url OUTBOUND SETTINGS: ack=true
10:17:50.725 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url INBOUND WINDOW_UPDATE: streamId=0 windowSizeIncrement=2147418112
10:17:50.726 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url INBOUND SETTINGS: ack=true
10:17:50.773 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url INBOUND HEADERS: streamId=3 headers=GrpcHttp2ResponseHeaders[:status: 200, content-type: application/grpc, x-unique-req-id: 6456D0E0_AA6B645628F31F906539BE3E1C1D1] padding=0 endStream=false
10:17:50.778 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url INBOUND DATA: streamId=3 padding=0 endStream=false length=7 bytes=00000000020801
10:17:50.778 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url OUTBOUND PING: ack=false bytes=1234
10:17:50.782 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url INBOUND HEADERS: streamId=3 headers=GrpcHttp2ResponseHeaders[grpc-status: 0, grpc-message: ] padding=0 endStream=true
10:17:50.783 [DEBUG] c.g.p.g.g.p.GrpcProtocol$ - Warm up request successful
10:17:50.786 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x18efc0a2, L:/10.80.74.193:51432 - R:url OUTBOUND GO_AWAY: lastStreamId=0 errorCode=0 length=0 bytes=
Simulation test.scala.PaymentFinalizerProcess started...
10:17:50.792 [TRACE] i.g.app.Runner - Asking Controller to start
10:17:50.804 [INFO ] i.g.c.s.w.ConsoleDataWriter - Initializing
10:17:50.804 [INFO ] i.g.c.s.w.LogFileDataWriter - Initializing
10:17:50.819 [INFO ] i.g.c.s.w.ConsoleDataWriter - Initialized
10:17:50.829 [INFO ] i.g.c.s.w.LogFileDataWriter - Initialized
10:17:50.842 [TRACE] i.g.c.c.i.o.OpenWorkload - Injecting 1 users in scenario PaymentFinalizerProcess, continue=false
10:17:50.842 [INFO ] i.g.c.c.i.o.OpenWorkload - Scenario io.gatling.core.scenario.Scenario@46ef27ae has finished injecting
10:17:50.843 [INFO ] i.g.c.c.i.Injector - All scenarios have finished injecting
10:17:50.850 [DEBUG] c.g.p.g.g.s.BidiStreamCall - Opening stream 'PaymentFinalizerProcess': Scenario 'PaymentFinalizerProcess', UserId #1
10:17:50.873 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x3af7fdc3, L:/10.80.74.193:51433 - R:url OUTBOUND SETTINGS: ack=false settings={ENABLE_PUSH=0, MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS=0, INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE=1048576, MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE=8192}
10:17:50.874 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x3af7fdc3, L:/10.80.74.193:51433 - R:url OUTBOUND WINDOW_UPDATE: streamId=0 windowSizeIncrement=983041
10:17:50.883 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x3af7fdc3, L:/10.80.74.193:51433 - R:url INBOUND SETTINGS: ack=false settings=[id: 0x3af7fdc3, L:/10.80.74.193:51433 - R:url
10:17:50.884 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x3af7fdc3, L:/10.80.74.193:51433 - R:url OUTBOUND SETTINGS: ack=true
10:17:50.885 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x3af7fdc3, L:/10.80.74.193:51433 - R:url OUTBOUND HEADERS: streamId=3 headers=GrpcHttp2OutboundHeaders[:authority: url, :path: /relay.RelayServer/PaymentFinalizerProcess, :method: POST, :scheme: http, content-type: application/grpc, te: trailers, user-agent: grpc-java-netty/1.46.0, authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.monLtqskKtLCuVNBz1Pw-oLPM3sWpC34E31HNa4tWlY, grpc-accept-encoding: gzip, grpc-timeout: 29963072u] streamDependency=0 weight=16 exclusive=false padding=0 endStream=false
10:17:50.896 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x3af7fdc3, L:/10.80.74.193:51433 - R:url INBOUND SETTINGS: ack=false settings={HEADER_TABLE_SIZE=4096, MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS=100, MAX_FRAME_SIZE=16384, MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE=65535}
10:17:50.897 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x3af7fdc3, L:/10.80.74.193:51433 - R:url OUTBOUND SETTINGS: ack=true
10:17:50.897 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x3af7fdc3, L:/10.80.74.193:51433 - R:url INBOUND WINDOW_UPDATE: streamId=0 windowSizeIncrement=2147418112
10:17:50.897 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x3af7fdc3, L:/10.80.74.193:51433 - R:url INBOUND SETTINGS: ack=true
10:17:51.002 [DEBUG] c.g.p.g.g.s.BidiStreamCall - Sending message device {
  id: "123dev123"tling / testOnly 3s
}
payment {
  relayPaymentId: "thisId"
  amount: 6000.0
  posName: "posName"
  posVersion: "posVersion"
  additionalInfo: "sunt fugiat ut commodo qui"
}
paymentResult {
  status: "test"
  paymentDetailString: "ut labore aliquip exercitation velit"
}
command: "PAYMENT_RESULT"
log: "abc"
 with stream 'PaymentFinalizerProcess': Scenario 'PaymentFinalizerProcess', UserId #1
10:17:51.009 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x3af7fdc3, L:/10.80.74.193:51433 - R:url] OUTBOUND DATA: streamId=3 padding=0 endStream=false length=185 bytes=00000000b40a0b0a093132336465763132331a600a2435393934343330362d626431362d346433632d616461622d663761643035306162383839110000000000...
10:17:51.010 [DEBUG] i.g.c.c.i.o.OpenWorkload - Start user #1
10:18:20.859 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x3af7fdc3, L:/10.80.74.193:51433 - R:url OUTBOUND RST_STREAM: streamId=3 errorCode=8
10:18:20.870 [TRACE] c.g.p.g.g.s.BidiStreamCall -
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Stream Close:
BIDIStream - PaymentFinalizerProcess: OK
=========================
Session:
Session(PaymentFinalizerProcess,1,Map(gatling.grpc.channel -> ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper{delegate=ManagedChannelImpl{logId=5, target=url}}),OK,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$489/0x00000135584eb710@5975dcbd,io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop@447ebb27)
=========================
gRPC stream completion:
status=
DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, description: deadline exceeded after 29.995212400s. [closed=[], open=[[buffered_nanos=32121500, remote_addr=url]]]
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10:18:20.870 [DEBUG] i.g.c.a.Exit - End user #1
10:18:20.871 [DEBUG] i.g.n.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x3af7fdc3, L:/10.80.74.193:51433 - R:[url] OUTBOUND GO_AWAY: lastStreamId=0 errorCode=0 length=0 bytes=
10:18:20.875 [DEBUG] i.g.c.c.i.Injector - End user #PaymentFinalizerProcess
10:18:20.875 [INFO ] i.g.c.c.i.Injector - All users of scenario PaymentFinalizerProcess are stopped
10:18:20.876 [INFO ] i.g.c.c.i.Injector - Stopping
10:18:20.876 [INFO ] i.g.c.c.Controller - Injector has stopped, initiating graceful stop
```

my logback.xml is in src/test/resources, with content below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{15} - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
    </appender>

    <!-- uncomment and set to DEBUG to log all failing HTTP requests -->
    <!-- uncomment and set to TRACE to log all HTTP requests -->
    <!--<logger name="io.gatling.http.engine.response" level="TRACE" />-->

    <!-- uncomment to log WebSocket events -->
    <logger name="io.gatling.http.action.ws.fsm" level="TRACE" />

    <!-- uncomment to log SSE events -->
    <logger name="io.gatling.http.action.sse.fsm" level="TRACE" />

    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 5 log leves in logback, in ascending levels of importance: `TRACE`, `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARN`, `ERROR`.

> I think that the log level maybe being low, so I have set the root level in logback.xml to WARN level, but nothing changed

You got it the wrong way round. To see all the messages of the stream in the logs, you should use the **lowest** level `TRACE`.
Again, have you tried ChatGPT? Give it that quoted sentence and you'll be aware of your misconception.